# Return null for date_format when input is null in mysql

Tags: mysql, null, date-format

I'm doing something like this:

```
SELECT date_format(mydate, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM xyz;
```

When mydate is NULL, date_format returns 00/00/0000. This is correct, but how can I make it so that it returns NULL when the input is NULL?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT IF(mydate,date_format(mydate, '%d/%m/%Y'),NULL) FROM xyz;
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap this into a `IF`-Clause, like this:

```
SELECT IF(mydate,DATE_FORMAT(mydate, '%d/%m/%Y'),NULL) FROM xyz;
```

That said, if your variable `mydate` is not a date value, the query in your post should return `(NULL)` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
case 
    when date_format(mydate, '%d/%m/%Y') = 00/00/0000 then null
    else ///
end as mydate,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when isnull(mydate) then null else date_format(mydate, '%d/%m/%Y') end as mydate from xyz;
```